# Is the ansible amazon ec2_instance properly idempotent and how to make it so?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I can create an EC2 instance when I run the playbook once and then use information from the instance to do further things.

(eg display the instance IDs to the screen so the user knows what was created and can do further manual tasks.)

If I run the same playbook again, with no changes the result of the ec2_instance module is "nothing changed" and it does not contain any of the "return values" that the instance held.

eg :

```
- name: Create EC2 Instance
  ec2_instance:
    image_id: ami-02b9b693377a07477
    wait: true
    name: "{{ ec2_tag }}"
    exact_count: 1
  register: ec2
- name: Print instance
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: ec2
```

Gives me :

```
TASK [aws : Create EC2 Instance] **************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [aws : Print instance] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2": {
        "changed": true,
        "failed": false,
        "instance_ids": [
            "i-0390a772d4a60fb83"
        ],
        "instances": [
            {
                "ami_launch_index": 0,
                "architecture": "x86_64",
......
```

on the FIRST run.

But, if I re-run :

```
TASK [aws : Create EC2 Instance] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [aws : Print instance] *******************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "ec2": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "msg": "1 instances already running, nothing to do."
    }
}
```

If I do the same sort of thing with a VPC or an IGW then the debug lines show the ID of the igw/vpc as expected. But figuring out which EC2 is already running seems to be quite hard without using ec2_instances_info and recreating the exact filter selection used to find the instance.

I did try `state: restarted` and a few other tricks to see if it would consider making a modification :

```
    purge_tags: true
    tags:
      date: "{{ ansible_date_time.iso8601 }}"
```

But it doesn't even want to change the tag to the new value. Once the instance is created once, it seems you can't change it or get any info about it...

(It's been years since I used ansible, so apologies if there is an obvious answer!)

Comment: What is the question? is it how to update the tags of the EC2 instance? then I would suggest to look at the [ec2_tag](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_tag_module.html) module. If the question is how to retrieve information from an existing EC2 instance, then I would suggest to read about the [ec2_instance_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/ec2_instance_info_module.html) module

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas The question is how to use the ec2_instances mod idempotently! If I define an IGW and run the playbook twice, it does not say "IGW already running" it returns props of the existing IGW. If I define an EC2 and run the playbook twice it does not get any props. I don't want to change the instance now, but next time I run the play, I need it to get the props of the instance. The same way IGW/VPC/etc... works.

Comment: `ec2_instances` is idempotent; if the asset does not need to change it wouldn't be changed that is the response `ok`. If the asset has any difference to the one set in the playbook, then Ansible will do the changes required and the response will be `changed`

Comment: Also note that `ec2_instances` does not retrieve the information of the AWS EC2 instance; `ec2_instance_info` do. Maybe the confusion is caused because when the asset is created or modified, then the result will contain the information of the asset created/modified; but that may not be always the case, as Ansible will only do changes when it is needed to do so.

Comment: @CarlosMonroyNieblas NO, it is not idempotent. If I run the same playbook twice, the first will succeed and the second will fail. It is also inconsistent with many  other modules. And it does not update the instance with the new tags. It should not return "changed": false when the tag is changed. Also if I set state: restarted it does not restart the instance. And if I change instance_type it does not change the type. It just seems totally broken to me.

Comment: Yeah, very broken... https://github.com/ansible-collections/amazon.aws/issues/469. I'd add some more issues to their backlog. Except there is already a lot of fundamental old broken things. I'm just going back to Cloudformation instead.

Comment: please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we will be able to help you.